# Is it possible to Delete a value passed to a method, from within the method

Tags: php

Say I have a method (which in this particular case is a static method), and this method works on a given value. Once completed is there a way that I can automatically in the code, delete the variable (rather than the function copy).

I suspect from all I've read that this is not possible, but there are no clear declarations of such that my searching has found.

**An example case:**

Static Method:

```
public static function checkKey($keyValue = null)
{
    if(!is_null($keyValue) && !empty($keyValue)) {
        if($_SESSION['keyValue'] == $keyValue) {
            unset($keyValue,$_SESSION['keyValue']);
            return true;
        }
        unset($keyValue,$_SESSION['keyValue']);
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Usage:

```
$valueToBeChecked = "I want this value unset from within the function"
//PHP page code 
AbstractClass::checkKey($valueToBeChecked);
```

Is there a way that the method `checkKey` above can delete the value of `$valueToBeChecked` *from within the method `checkKey`*?

The fact it's a static method shouldn't be too critical, it's more the shape of is there a way that the function can delete a value that is set outside the funtion/method, when passed the variable as a parameter?

I realise this is possible if the whole thing is wrapped in a Class and the variable is saved as a class level variable (`unset($this->var)`), but I'm curious if there's any ability to "reach" variables from outside the scope such as

```
public static function checkKey($keyValue = null)
{
    unset(\$keyValue);
}
```

I only have limited experience with namespacing but that's my best guess as to if this is possible, how to go about it.

**simplified equiviliant outcome:**

What I'm trying to reach is this action, entirely within the method:

```
$valueToBeChecked = "something"
AbstractClass::checkKey($valueToBeChecked);
unset($valueToBeChecked);
```

Comment: So you want to know if a function can modify its caller's stack frame?

Comment: @bishop Yes that sounds like it.

Comment: I thought it might work if you pass the variable by reference [but it doesn't](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654538/php-function-to-unset-variables-passed-by-reference). I think actually this can't be done.

Comment: YOU SHOULD NOT do this. Pick a new design pattern. You should never ever need to do this.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/6654538/2908724

Comment: @self  I do not disagree at all, but can you say more about *why* this should not be done? For my instance I have a value that has a very specific job and once this job is done (the function) then I want to tidy up the value and remove it, as it's no longer needed.

Comment: You check a key then, as a side effect, remove the key. Avoid side effects. If a side effect *must* exist, make the effect obvious. The method name is `checkKey`, but its actual behavior with side effect is `checkKeyAndRemoveIfValueDoesNotMatch`. A function that needs a long name to describe what it's doing is a smell that the function does too much. Rather than do the tidy in the function, do the tidy in the parent, based on the return value. `if (! AbstractClass::checkKey($value)) { unset($value, $_SESSION['keyValue']); }`

Comment: @bishop I can see the logic there, but as a wider concept I was curious if there was a method for removing values set without a function, from within a function. Hence the question and your useful answer. I don't want to focus too much on my specific case, rather as a general approach as to *if* this action is possible. If this action is in general *unwise* (as mentioned by Self) perhaps this detail could be added to your answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot unset a variable from within a function and have that effect propagate. Per the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php):

> If a variable that is PASSED BY REFERENCE is unset() inside of a function, only the local variable is destroyed. The variable in the calling environment will retain the same value as before unset() was called.

However, you can get equivalent behavior through pass-by-reference and setting to null:

```
function kill(&$value) {
    $value = null;
}

var_dump($x); // NULL
$x = 'foo';
var_dump($x); // 'foo'
kill($x);
var_dump($x); // NULL
```

This works because, in PHP, there's no distinction made between a symbol that doesn't exist and a symbol that exists with a `NULL` value.

Comment: This kind of programming should be avoided at all costs.

Comment: @self I agree. It's a side-effect bear trap.

Comment: This answer does enough to cover what I was looking for, thanks.